# SVN - create new repository

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I would like to import files from svn but I ger error.

WAMP 2.0 (for test svn)

```
Eroor Redirect cycle detected for URL 'localhost:8080/SystemKontroliWersji'
```

picture 1 - here I create new repository "SystemKontroliWersji"

[image]

picture 2 - here I add C# file "TreningToWork"

[image]

picture 3 - now I would like to imort this "TreningToWork" from svn but I get error

[image]

picture 4 - I can`t go to "TreningToWork"

[image]

Comment: Why do you create a repository in the existing repository? 0_o

Comment: @bahrep Actually, I'm sure its documented somewhere for SVN to have _one_ root repo and make all subsequent ones children of that, as a matter of preferred convention.

Comment: Is the URL not supposed to be something more like "http://localhost:8080/SystemKontroliWersji/TreningToWork/", seeing as you are trying to checkout something within that repo? Apologies if I've misunderstood :) You can always check by right-clicking in Explorer and going to TortoiseSVN > Repo Browser

Comment: @baldric but I can`t go to TreningToWork

Comment: @Rafael-JuniorMVCDeveloper you create a repo not in the repo root, but inside of existing repository. conf / db / hooks / locks are the "backend" of a svn repository.

Comment: Are you sure that tortoise is serving that repo over http? If it's a local one, wouldn't it make more sense to checkout from a local address? Tortoise is a *client*, after all

Comment: @bahrep but when I put project into one of this file it`s also not visible for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to create and access the repository without using a server, you have to use local address:

> To access your local repository you need the path to that folder. Just remember that Subversion expects all repository paths in the form file:///C:/SVNRepository/. Note the use of forward slashes throughout.

Taken from [Tortoise Manual](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-repository.html#tsvn-repository-local-access).

If you want http access, VisualSVN is a decent free one for Windows.

---

Anyway, you are terribly overcomplicating things and doing something essentially wrong here. I suggest you first read the manual I've linked, and then probably use the VisualSVN to grok how all this really works.

Comment: I get this -> URL 'file:///C:/wamp/www/SystemKontroliWersji/conf/TreningToWork' doesn't exist